# Option to hide rep/badges on the avatar block displayed of you

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, reputation, badges

Allow the user to hide its own reputation value and/or badges similarly as visible on wiki pages. If the visitor wants to know your reputation, he/she has to view it on your user page.

Scenarios why to do it:

- You have so much rep/badge, that *your name gets recognized* wherever you post
- You want to be *just helpful* and you show this by not advertising how 'good repped' you are, but rather focus on a good answer
- Implicit *'reputation' by name* within the community - same as in the real world

Scenarios why not to do it:

- Could impose transparency problems regarding to the site's basic concepts
- Hard to implement on a per user basis
- Concerns about showing/hiding it in the question part or in answers.

Discussion welcome.

<sub>Follow-up to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/why-are-the-badge-counts-displayed-beside-the-posters-avatar) of mine.</sub>

Comment: Bounty: I really want to clear things about this question for good so I can close it. I guess it will be eventually declined ;)

Comment: I would say, thank you, in name of one of my program's functionality :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your name is recognized, then removing the rep/badges isn't going to do anything - your *name* will still be there... unless you were planning on making posts anonymous before a hover/click-through.

I see your point, but I'm not sure there's really a *problem* at the moment that this would solve. I think there would *have* to be a way of tracing a question/answer back to a person to avoid the [anonymity idiocy problem](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2004/03/19/). The rest of it would probably be quite simple - I doubt that it would actually be hard to implement.

In short, I'm not *against* the idea, but I don't think it's particularly necessary either.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I felt you would answer.

Comment: Everybody recognizes Skeet because of his avatar.

Comment: Thank you. How about the reason to avoid this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/hide-exact-reputation-value-from-mass-listings :)