# Filter users by badge

Tags: feature-request, user-search

Could it be useful to find users with, say, gold badge in C++: to have some inspiration in their questions and answers?

Comment: I don't know a search that would give you those users, but this is a direct link to the relevant list: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/49/

Comment: If you want to be more specific, you can compose your own query on: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: Just to be more general, the users with any badge are listed under that badge--just click on the badge and start paging.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131020/show-answerers-related-badges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the users with the C++ gold badge:

1. Go to the Badges page
2. Click tags
3. [Click gold c++](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/49/c)

By the way, you can also hoover above the C++ tag and select [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/topusers) for the top 20 in the c++ tag.

Both methods also work for other tags.